# Conflicting column height overflow on a fixed table. Using bootstrap 3 with MVC 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I found a solution on how to fixed a table with scroll bar by creating another class `.tablecontainer`, but in this case I need to add a drop-down list on one column so my table adjusted its height according to the drop-down cell column, I need to adjust all rows, according to drop-down cell's height.

A screenshot of the state is:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        vertical-align: central;
    }
    .tablecontainer {
        width: 1000px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    tr {
        display: block;
    }
    th, td {
        width: 500 px;
    }
    tbody {
        display: block;
        height: 400px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .table tbody > tr > td.vert-align {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="padding: 70px">
    <h3 style="font-family:'Century Gothic'"></h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style= "column-width:100px; text-align:center">Employee No.</th>
                <th style= "column-width:200px; text-align:center">Employee Name</th>
                <th style= "column-width:100px; text-align:center"">Status</th>
                <th style= "column-width:100px; text-align:center"">Training Title</th>
                <th style= "column-width:100px; text-align:center"">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


            <tr>
                <td style= "column-width:100px; celltext-align:center">12345</td>
                <td style= "column-width:200px; text-align:center">Lardino, Bryan S.</td>
                <td style= "column-width:100px; text-align:center">For Approval</td>
                <td style= "column-width:100px; text-align:center">Wave Training</td>
                <td style= "column-width:100px; text-align:center"><div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Approved</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Disapproved</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style= "column-width:100px; text-align:center">12345</td>
                <td style= "column-width:200px; text-align:center">Lardino, Bryan S.</td>
                <td style= "column-width:100px; text-align:center">For Approval</td>
                <td style= "column-width:100px; text-align:center">Wave Training</td>
                <td style= "column-width:100px; text-align:center"><div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Approved</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Disapproved</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="row" style="height: 50px">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default pull-right" href="#")>Submit</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The height seems fine to me in Chrome ([Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/V6LAj3mDR2)).

Comment: im using ie9, is there any solution?

Comment: and i want also the column size for the headers will be followed by the  body

Comment: Inline image and code formatting

Comment: try don't use divs with tables